# SQL Squirrel vs Java

Tags: hsqldb, squirrel-sql

I am using SQL Squirrel to create a HyperSQLDB. I am using the HyperSQLDB from java.

The problem is when the database is open using SQL Squirrel i can't connect to it from java JDBC. 
I need to close SQL Squirrel to use the database from java. If not i receive the message: `java.sql.SQLException: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile`

The only way is to close SQL Squirrel. Is there anyway to disconnect from database, instead of close SQL Squirrel? Or othe solution.

Thanks

Comment: If you SHUTDOWN the dabase in Squirrel, it disconnects.

Answer (score 1):

You should run a HyperSQL server. That way, you can have multiple connections at the same time, as all programs connect to the server which manages access.

You can start a server like this:

```
 java -cp lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:mydb --dbname.0 testdb
```

This starts a server with one (default) database. The DB files are named "mydb.*" and the public name of the database is "testdb".

For details, see the HyperSQL docs: [Chapter 1. Running and Using HyperSQL  - Server modes](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_server_modes)